# "No rows were georeferenced" error in CartoDB

Tags: carto, geocoding

I am trying to geolocate my data by the city name and country, but receive an error:

> No rows were georeferenced It seems that some of your rows didn't
>   finish successfully. Perhaps these rows contained empty values or
>   perhaps we just didn't know what the values meant. We encourage you to
>   take a look and try again.

Basically, I have an .xls dataset with columns: Data - that contain data of patent codes; City - the city where this patent registered; and Country - Italy. I've been trying to map the location for patents, but I did not succeed with even one address. What might I be doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the previous post. The message of the system is following: "No rows were georeferenced

It seems that some of your rows didn't finish successfully. Perhaps these rows contained empty values or perhaps we just didn't know what the values meant. We encourage you to take a look and try again." Basically, I have an .xls dataset with columns: Data - that contain data of patent codes; City - the city where this patent registered; and Country - Italy. I've been trying to map the location for patents, but I did not succeed with even 1 address.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CartoDB, but in looking at the [georeference tutorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/how_to_georeference.html) I'm wondering if your column names might be the problem - some of them are fairly long and have spaces in them. You might try changing them to things like 'patent' 'city' 'province' and if you must have a space use underscore instead. If that doesn't work, you should probably edit your question to include the precise steps you've taken in trying to do the georeferencing, so we know what methods and settings were used.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I did a test in my own account and it seems to be working: https://team.cartodb.com/u/iriberri/tables/italy_names/table

Some things for you to take into account:

- Try to avoid leading spaces after your city names. "Pavia " instead of "Pavia" will make the system fail at the moment. Obviously this is a bug we will fix asap.
- The cartodb_georef_status will avoid your rows to be geocoded if it's set as "false" or "true". Being "null" for all your column shouldn't have any effect, but you can also remove the column in order to be sure.

Check also your Excel file: does is have trailing spaces after the city names?

If the trailing spaces is not solving the issue, we'd need you to share your table contents. For example, exporting the table as CSV and copying the contents in your initial post would be helpful. This way we can check if there are some conflictive characters or information missing.

To complete the answer, I'm attaching a screenshot of my table and the process that I configured:

[image: Table view]
[image: Georef con]
[image: Georef congid 2]
[image: Result]

Comment: The trailing spaces are still an issue as of Aug 2015